# Can we apply noHistory=true to the complete application in android manifest file

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

In my application, I have 6 pages, when user clicks backbutton the previous screen should not displayed, (previous activity  should not be saved), so temporarily I have written 
`android:noHistory="true"`, for each activity in the manifest file, As there are 6 activites, I repeated the same command for 6 times.

But can we apply `android:noHistory="true"` to the complete application in android manifest file by writing at the `<application>` tag, so that we can write the command only once?

Comment: The `<application>` tag does not support the `android:noHistory=""` attribute. but do try it at your end. I suppose, you will have to add it to every Activity which you want to apply the attribute to. I don't really see why that should be a problem though. It is not something that is time consuming, nor is it something that you need to change often. Set it once, and pretty much forget about it kinda thing eh? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Since noHistory attribute is only available for activity tags only and apart from the activities application contains the registration for services and broadcast receivers, you can not add that at any single place in your manifest file to reference all the activities to that value.